# The Handlebars.js is not appending values to my page

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

```
var name;
var what;
var sol;
var i;
var biasData;
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET","biases.json", true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(http.readyState === 4) {
    if(http.status >= 200 && http.status <= 400) {
      biasData = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
      console.log(biasData);
      var data = biasData.slice(0,1);
      console.log(data);
      // var data = biasData.splice(0,1);
      // console.log(data);
      // i = 0;
      // var length = biasData.length;
      // setInterval(function() {
      //   name = biasData[i]["name"];
      //   what = biasData[i]["explanation"];
      //   sol = biasData[i]["solution"];
      //   i++;
      //   if(i >= length) {
      //     i = 0;
      //   }
      // }, 10000);
      var templateScript = document.getElementById('bias').innerHTML;
      var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
      var compiledTemp = theTemplate(data);
      document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = compiledTemp;

    }
  }
};
http.send();

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learning Handlebars.js</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">

    </div>
    <script id="bias" type="x-handlebars-template">
        <h1 id="name">{{name}}</h1>
        <p id="what">{{explanation}}</p>
        <p id="sol">{{solution}}</p>
    </script>
    <a href="#"><button type="button" name="button">Read more at Wikipedia</button></a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="handle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code is not appending values to my page. I am not getting any error either.

This my json data

```
[{
    "name": "Survivorship Bias",
    "explanation": "It causes you to overestimate your chances of success. For example, you found a startup and think of it as the next Google, but you don't realise the fact that behind every successful startup there are way many company that don't even make it off the starting line, and out of those who take off, a lot many go bankrupt within first three years.",
    "solution": "This doesn't mean that you don't even try, but neglecting the correct odds can cause to come up with a terrible plan. A better way to deal with this is to be aware of people's failures too. Take note of the reality, and plan accordingly. "
},
{
    "name": "Swimmer's Body Illusion",
    "explanation": "Have you ever watched a commercial of a cosmetic, in which your favorite actress is endorsing that cosmetic? You think that you should buy that as it will make you look like your favorite actress. The problem is, cosmetic doesn't make your actress look the way she does. The actress is born attractive, and hence, is the chosen candidate for that advertisement.",
    "solution": "Be honest about yourself. It's not that if you got an MBA, then you'd earn all the money in the world. It's only if you have the best skills, then you'd earn all the money in the world." 
},
{
    "name": "Clustering Illusion",
    "explanation": "'Look! The cloud looks like a tortoise.' Haven't you said that before? You may have heard viral stories of people, who observed the face of one of the many Gods on a potato. It is normal. Human brain loves to seek patterns. The worst part is, if your brain can't find a obvious patter, then it will make one.",
    "solution": "Don't neglect the possibility of something happening by chance. Not everything happens for a reason, sometimes it is just our brain that is messing with us."
},
{
    "name": "Social Proof",
    "explanation": "How often do you do things just because others are doing it too? Let's understand, why we do it. Back in the days of being a cavemen, it was a good survival strategy. When we knew less about our world, it was better to run for our lives, when others were too.",
    "solution": "Don't buy something just because everybody is buying it. Look for whether or not if buying it can help you with your situation. "
}
]
```

I've been following javascript is sexy's tutorial, and two youtube videos, but no one mentioned this situation.

Any help would be great.

EDIT: I further tested, it is the JSON data retrived that causing the problem. Although, `data` is getting logged in the console, but somehow the Handlebars function is not able to read it.

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: Oh, I have figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I have figured out the solution. If you are someone who is in the similar situation. then take a look at the data that you are passing to the template.

In my case `data` is an array. So I had to use `data[0]` to access the object.